# Is Smite Evil damage multiplied by a critical hit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, paladin

In Pathfinder, smite damage adds +paladin level (or 2 × paladin level) to damage when smiting evil. The rules for critical hits say:

> A critical hit means that you roll
>   your damage more than once, with all
>   your usual bonuses, and add the rolls
>   together.... Exception: Precision
>   damage (such as from a rogue's sneak
>   attack class feature) and additional
>   damage dice from speacial weapon
>   qualities (such as flaming) are not
>   multiplied when you score a critical
>   hit. — *P. 184*

I'm not sure whether smite evil counts as precision damage. Does Smite Evil damage get multiplied, or not? Thoughts, rulings?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Smite damage is not precision damage, and since it is extra points not extra dice of damage, it is definitely multiplied.  The only things not multiplied on crits are extra dice of damage, such as precision damage or weapon effects like flaming.

Comment: To elaboreate on the above - +[Number] ALWAYS multiplies, but +XdX NEVER multiplies. Easiest way to remember it.

Comment: Also, nothing is really *multiplied* as much as rolled multiple times. d8+5 on a crit would be rolled twice, possibly resulting in (4+5) + (1+5) damage.

Answer (score 0):

When you crit you only multiply the dice you roll not the damage you add though. Example: your greatsword rolls 2d6 on attack and 1d6 fire damage, you crit and roll 8 on the 2d6 and 3 on the fire damage, you also have a +4 str bonus. So you multiply the 8 to 16 then add the 3 fire damage and your strength bonus which adds 6 damage since you are wielding a two handed weapon, this makes for a total of 16+3+6=25 damage

Comment: Extra dice yes, but static bonuses are multiplied. With the exception of precision damage and abilities that say they dont multiply.

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed multiply the smite damage and the strength modifier.

*"Multiplying Damage*

*Sometimes you multiply damage by some factor, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage **(with all modifiers)** multiple times and total the results.
Note: When you multiply damage more than once, each multiplier works off the original, unmultiplied damage. So if you are asked to double the damage twice, the end result is three times the normal damage.
Exception: Extra damage dice over and above a weapon’s normal damage are never multiplied."*

Using the other example: your greatsword rolls 2d6 on attack and 1d6 fire damage, you crit and roll 8 on the 2d6 and 3 on the fire damage, you also have a +4 str bonus. So you add the 8 and your strength bonus which adds 6 damage since you are wielding a two handed weapon getting 14. We will also assume that you have used Smite and your target was Evil and your paladin level is 5 since this was your question. We add the 5 to the 14 and get 19. Since you crit we do it again. Rolling the 2d6 again we get 7. Add our 6 for strength and 5 for smite for 18. Add the two damage rolls together for 37 and then add the 3 fire damage, this makes for a total of (8+6+5)+(7+6+5)+3 = 40